# Java - error: cannot find symbol - switch / case

Tags: java, compilation, switch-statement, case

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie einen Betrag und den Buchstaben der gewunschten Wahrung ein.");

    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double betrag = input.nextInt();
        String wahrung = input.next();     
        double result = 0;

        switch(wahrung.charAt(0)) {
            case d:
                result = betrag * 1.18;
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
            case p:
                result = betrag * 0.88;
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
            case f:
                result = betrag * 0.88;
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie eine Zahl ein.");
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it, it says:

```
Rechner.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
                case d:
                     ^
  symbol:   variable d
  location: class Rechner
Rechner.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
                case p:
                     ^
  symbol:   variable p
  location: class Rechner
Rechner.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
                case f:
                     ^
  symbol:   variable f
  location: class Rechner
```

Comment: it's char `'p'` not only `p`

Comment: Awesome, I hate these little things..

Comment: keep it up , u will get the hang of it  :)

Answer (score 2):

You use you switch with a `char`, so each case should also be a char value.

Try

```
switch(wahrung.charAt(0)) {
            case 'd':
                result = betrag * 1.18;
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
            case 'p':
                result = betrag * 0.88;
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
            case 'f':
                result = betrag * 0.88;
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
        }
```